# PHP : Schedule a task at user specific date and time

Tags: php, cron

I need to create a functionality like google calendar, where user have rights to change the date and time for reminder to get email or sms. I have googled and found that only solution is to use cron job.

However cron jobs runs at specific time repeatedly ( based on how we set it ). We can do it via cron job. But what i want in that case, user can change the time of reminder and then how to maintain it via cron job? Kind of user specific cron job

Does it mean dynamically creating a cron job? It is possible? 
If Yes, is there server permission issue? I have shared hosting server.

Comment: You don't create ad hoc cron jobs for each user/request, you create a cron job to read a message queue that you push new messages to with date/times to send, and clear the message queue items as you send the jobs.

Comment: @JaredFarrish can you please provide some more details on it or link where can I read it? I haven't used Message queues.

Comment: Create a table in your database. Add columns for each of your message details (maybe separate tables by email and sms, for simplicity). Add a row for the date/time to send. Setup a cron to run periodically which reads the rows from the table(s) (according to the timestamp) and performs the send action, removing or updating the rows as completed. Then push your messages to the table(s) as needed. In Java there is Quartz Scheduler, not sure if there is an equivalent in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

A solution may be to set the cron job every minute

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/html/a.php
```

and in your script you check all users having alerts current_hour:current_minute and send them alerts ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP Library you can use to carry the task, install it via,

```
composer require hutnikau/job-scheduler
```

and here is the sample code,

```php
$startTime = new \DateTime('2017-12-12 20:00:00');
 $rule = new \Scheduler\Job\RRule('FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=5', $startTime); //run monthly, at 
 20:00:00 starting from the 12th of December 2017, 5 times
 $job = new \Scheduler\Job\Job($rule, function () {
    //do something
 });
```

Setup library and required cron job by the job scheduler, otherwise it won't work.

As an alternative you can use `Cron Job` in your server, `Cron Job` simply executes the script defined in the job periodically. By using `Cron Job` you will be able to control how many times it should execute in the year, month, day, hour, minute and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The `at` command will let you schedule one off tasks to run, similar to cron. The "run a cron job every minute" will work until each one is doing so much work that execution time exceeds 60 seconds.

Honestly, this sounds like it should be handled via a message queue or workers.